# delegate and methods aren't executing without a reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Problem is : have action(touch inside button) where I am saving object to core data, and if all goes right, dismissing controller. But controller is not dismissing and my delegate isn't working too. I tried to debug and found that information is valid and saving, but delegate and dismissing aren't working for unknown reason.

Here is code:
Action:

```
- (IBAction)acceptDayOfWeek:(id)sender
{
    managedObjectContext = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].managedObjectContext;

    int selectedString = [dayOfWeekPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSDate *weekDayUnknwn = [days objectAtIndex:selectedString];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    weekDayForSave = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:weekDayUnknwn];

    ReadySubject *readySubject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ReadySubject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    readySubject.dayOfWeek = weekDayForSave;


    NSError *error;
    if ([managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        [self.delegate changeWeekDay];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

delegate

```
#pragma mark ChangeDayOfWeekDelegate

- (void) changeWeekDay
{
    [dateLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    [self makingArrayOfWeekDays];
}
```

method that realized in delegate

```
- (NSArray *)takeDayOfWeekFromCoreData
{
    managedObjectContext = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ReadySubject" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:description];

    NSError *requestError = nil;

    dayOfWeekArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&requestError] mutableCopy];

    if (requestError) {
        NSLog(@"%@" , [requestError localizedDescription]);
    }
    return dayOfWeekArray;

}

- (void)makingArrayOfWeekDays
{
    [self takeDayOfWeekFromCoreData];
    dayOfWeekIndexesArray = [dayOfWeekArray valueForKey:@"dayOfWeek"];
    if ([dayOfWeekIndexesArray count] != 0) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [dayOfWeekIndexesArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
}
```

setting delegate

```
@protocol ChangeDayOfWeekDelegate

- (void) changeWeekDay;

@end

@interface ChageDayOfWeekViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <ChangeDayOfWeekDelegate> delegate;
```

and

```
#import "ChageDayOfWeekViewController.h"

@interface ScheduleViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, MakingEventViewControllerDelegate, ChangeDayOfWeekDelegate>
```

Comment: Is your delegate definitely set (not nil)?

Comment: @pbasdf added in the end of the post. If I understood what you are asking about.

Comment: You only conforms to ChangeDayOfWeekDelegate, I couldn't see where you setting the delegate in your code snippet?

Comment: So by the looks of it, your ScheduleViewController creates and presents ChageDayOfWeekViewController.  I can see that it has a delegate property, but do you set the delegate before presenting the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What pbasdf is saying is that the delegate is probably `nil` if the code is not executed. To check this you can change the code in your Action as following and then post the result.

```
if ([managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
    if (self.delegate) {
        NSLog(@"delegate is set");
        [self.delegate changeWeekDay];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"delegate is not set and can not execute code");
    }            
    NSLog(@"If I reach this part of code and I am the ViewController I should be dismissed");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If this is not the reason I have to say that your code-snippets are irritating because one can not see what belongs to what, you should post always the filename on top.

Comment: @Chrisitan 2014-11-16 02:25:04.319 StudentSchedule[4361:233804] delegate is not set and can not execute code
2014-11-16 02:25:04.319 StudentSchedule[4361:233804] If I reach this part of code and I am the ViewController I should be dismissed

so, with delegate, how can i set it?

and controller didn't dismiss too

Comment: You will set the delegate right after in the place where you have created an instance of ChageDayOfWeekViewController.

Comment: How do you present the ChageDayOfWeekController?  By segue from the table view?  Or in code, from didSelectRow?

Comment: I do not understand the context of your classes, but if you have object A and create object B, where B should have A as Delegate, then you set B.delegate = A (probably in class A when you create B). If your viewController is not dismissed, this is another problem, but then we need to understand the ViewController stack. I would recommend making two questions out of it.

Comment: I suspect your view controller is not dismissed because you have pushed the VC onto a navigation controller, not presented it modally.  Try `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:]` instead of `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:]`

Comment: @pbasdf I understood. I am pushing it from ScheduleViewController, and I need to add [changeDayofWeek setDelegate:self]; Christian how can I explain ViewController stuck?

Comment: like pbasdf asked: how do you present the viewController that you want to dismiss. By segue or do you happen to make `pushViewController`? `dismissViewController` only works if you present it by `presentViewController`

Comment: Works! I don't know, why this happens, cause I did 3 same class in this way(about dismissing) and it works well. About delegate, it is bad mistake, i know. Thank you